# Python: Dictionary to Spare Vector

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and programming in general. I was working on Pyschool exercises Topic 8, Q 11 on converting Dictionary to Spare Vectore.

I was asked to Write a function that converts a dictionary back to its sparese vector representation.

Examples

```
>>> convertDictionary({0: 1, 3: 2, 7: 3, 12: 4})
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
>>> convertDictionary({0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1})
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> convertDictionary({})
[]
```

I have attempted many times. Below is the latest code I have:

```
def convertDictionary(dictionary):
    k=dictionary.keys()
    v=dictionary.values()
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,max(k)):
        result.append(0)
        for j in k:
            result[j]=v[k.index(j)]
    return result
```

The returned error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Code", line 8, in convertDictionary
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Could anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: You attempt to access list elements before the list has been constructed. First, create a list of all zeros `vector=[0]*max(k)`. Then, use your inner loop to update non-zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should suffice:

```
M = max(dictionary, default=0)
vector = [dictionary.get(i, 0) for i in range(M)]
```

Translated into a plain old for-loop

```
M = max(dictionary, default=0)
vector = []
for i in range(M):
    vector.append(dictionary.get(i, 0))
```

The `get` method lets you provide a default as a second argument in case the key is missing. Once you get more advance you could use a `defaultdict`

Edit: the default parameter for `max` requires Python >3.4 . You can either use exception handling (generally prefered) or explicit checks for empty dictionary to deal with that case if you have earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works logically fine, but you have a problem of indentation. Your function should be:

```
def convertDictionary(dictionary):
    k=dictionary.keys()
    v=dictionary.values()
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,max(k)):
        result.append(0)
    for j in k:
        result[j]=v[k.index(j)]
    return result
```

The problem is that your second `for` was inside of the first. What you want is to build a list with `max(k)` elements and then put the right values into it. Then, the two `for` loops should be one after the other, rather than one inside of the other.

Comment: @DYZ That's not the point, OP wants to know what is wrong with their code.

Comment: Yeah if we are going to change the first loop we would start by noting it's not necessary. Rarely do you ever need to prepopulate a list in Python.

Answer (score 0):

M = max(dictionary, default=0)

vector = [dictionary.get(i, 0) for i in range(M+1)]

Should always add 1 to range as final value is not inclusive so if range is 12 then only 11 iterations

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35501109)